# Is it possible to override flyway.url setting in flyway.conf from command line in flyway?

Tags: flyway

Is it possible to override url that is given in .conf file when invoking migrate from command line?

```
flyway -flyway.url=jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://test_sqlserver:1433/mydatabase migrate
```

This above does not seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Command-line options are not prefixed with `flyway.`

In your case this would mean

`flyway -url=jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://test_sqlserver:1433/mydatabase migrate`

Comment: I see. That's strange. _baseline_ command also has two command-line options called _baselineVersion_ and _baselineDescription_ yet the example `> flyway baseline -Dflyway.baselineVersion=1 -Dflyway.baselineDescription="Base version"` shows the _flyway_ prefix and it works. Or am I missing something there? By the way, what does _D_ in the option mean?

Answer (score 1):

To expand on that comment:

`-D` sets a system property (in this case `flyway.baselineVersion`), it's a parameter to java, not to flyway.

`-baselineVersion=1` is a parameter to flyway

Both happen to work only because flyway uses both command line arguments and system properties (in addition to the configuration file), they are not otherwise related.